# Dealing with discrete data when preprocessing

Tags: python, data-preprocessing

I have some data that is a mixture of continous and discrete- the type of category I am having issue is:

```
'Age at first period' :
1="<10"
2="10-11"
3="12-13"
4="14-15"
5="16+"
```

I need to transform it somehow to make it suitable for my ML models, but I am not sure the best way to do it.

One option is to one-hot encode it, but i don't think that's appropriate since it is ordinal. Another possibility is to leave it as it is, assuming it's continous but that doesn't seem right either, especially when it comes to filling in missing values with the mean or median, as I will do with other continous data. My final option is to replace each category with the mean number that the category covers- 1 will become 5, 2 will become 10.5, 3 will become 12.5 etc. But again, I dont know if this is correct.

Comment: Is data in same string format? or you just presented it as categorical in snippet? And `one-hot encoding` is not ordinal. `label-encoder` and `ordinal-encoder` is ordinal.

Comment: @GodWin, the data just appears as a '1' '2' '3' etc as an int, I have converted them to objects though so far. Haven't llooked into the label-encoder or ordinal-encoder so I will have a look now, thanks